# Can I show my domain name in links in a URL frame, or similar setup?

Tags: html, http, redirect, web, dns

I want something between a URL frame and URL redirect.

I have a domain called http://www.mydomain.com.

I have pages on my site. When I click on "page1.html", I would like the address bar of my browser to show "http://www.mydomain.com/page1.html". I want it to show this because then  users can click "back" or "forward" in their browsers.

Right now, my domain name provider (Namecheap) has two choices:

1. URL Frame: This always shows "http://www.mydomain.com", which messes up "back" and "forward" because the subpages aren't shown.
2. URL Redirect: This causes the address bar to show "http://www.uglydomain.com/subfolder/subsubfolder/page1.html".

What is the best solution? A silly, slightly incomplete solution would be to hard-code all of my links on my pages to "http://www.mydomain.com/page1.html". Can I achieve what I want through .htaccess, redirect rules, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if you had access to the site hosting the frame document, you could implement something with `pushState` and `postMessage`, but its *highly* unlikely that you do.

The only real solution is to get proper DNS hosting and point the DNS for the domain at the server hosting your website, and to have sufficiently good hosting that you can set up a virtual name host for the domain on your web server.

Comment: I have a lot of control of http://www.uglydomain.com/subfolder/subsubfolder/ ... can I do anything there to get what I want?

Comment: Not unless you have a very odd server configuration.